# Regex to remove underscore followed by number in string in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have set of strings like this:

```
CLM_ADJUSTMT.CLAIM_DATA.TUDCAP_L_2.CRT_TS_0, 
marks.science_0.physics_0,
marks.geo_1
```

I want to remove only if underscore is followed by number(CRT_TS_0=CRT_TS)
can someone help me to get the right regex

I tried using

```
  re.sub('_[0-9]+$', '',newstr)
```

but it removes all underscore and numbers

output:

```
CLM_ADJUSTMT.CLAIM_DATA.TUDCAP_L.CRT_TS,
marks.science.physics,
marks.geo
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Try [`re.sub(r'_(\d)', r'\1', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/6BAVtg/1)

Comment: Is that expected or current output? If expected, try `re.sub(r'_\d+', '', s)`, remove `$` in your pattern.

Comment: thank u so much :-)  re.sub(r'_\d+', '', s) this works!!

Answer (score 2):

As @wiktor said, remove the « $ »sign which means that your the string that you’re looking for has to FINISH with a _[0-9], not just contain.